# Google apps login in django

Tags: python, django, google-apps, django-openid-auth

I'm developing a django app that integrates with google apps. I'd like to let the users login with their google apps accounts (accounts in google hosted domains, *not google accounts*) so they can access their docs, calendar, and whatnot.

In order to do it, I downloaded and started using django_openid_auth (and thus, python-openid).

First, to test it, I used this url in my settings:

```
OPENID_SSO_SERVER_URL = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
```

And with that I managed to redirect the user to the google accounts page to login and then to return to my own domain, with the [authentication cycle](http://code.google.com/intl/es-AR/apis/apps/sso/openid_reference_implementation.html) described by the google folks successfuly completed. However, to login to google accounts is of little use for me, as I'd like the users who have a google apps account in their hosted domain -but not a google account- to login with.
In order to do that, I read the google article on discovery " Discovering OpenID Endpoints for Hosted Domains", and changed the aforementioned setting to:

```
OPENID_SSO_SERVER_URL = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=<my-domain>.com'
```

-where, obviously, `<my-domain>` is my actual domain ;)

But the backend responded with the following message:

> OpenID authentication failed: HTTP
>   Response status from identity URL host
>   is not 200. Got status 404

Debugging a little, I managed to find out that the code in python-openid (version 2.2.4) is the one that is misinterpreting the response from google, but I'm quite at loss here.

I have seen the authentication in my own domain work in socialwok.com and puffypoodles.com So I'm quite certain that the auth cycle for my google apps domain works, but somehow python-openid can't seem to complete it (though, and I reiterate, it works just fine with plain old google accounts).

Should I try to fix python-openid, or is there another way to fix this? Has anyone successfuly managed to login with google apps in a pure django app (**not in google app engine**)?

Comment: Diving into source of python-openid is probably the fastest way. Get the source, set it up with "python setup.py develop" and start instrumenting it with print statements or whatever your favorite debugging strategy is. Python code is usually readable and hackable, and you don't have to wait for responses in mailinglists / bugtrackers / SO...

Comment: @Pēteris Thanks, I wasn't aware of the `develop` switch. Nevertheless, I've been debugging the code and I found out that, when the yadis protocol tries to get the domain to prove that it is a provider indeed, it gets a 404 (by means of a simple urllib2 open method); So I'm guessing it happens because the domain admin hasn't registered my domain as a secure openID provider; but the question remains: why does puffypoodles.com authenticate without any problems? Is there something different between standard openID providers and the google hosted domains?

Comment: Post your code somewhere so I can try to reproduce and debug the issue you're seeing.

Comment: The Google URL mentioned isn't available.

Answer (score 8):

According to http://groups.google.com/group/google-federated-login-api/web/openid-discovery-for-hosted-domains, Google changed the way of IdP Discovery and user XRDS check a little bit to give Google Apps users openid in http://example.com/openid?id=108441225163454056756 kind of format without asking the users to build their own openid servers. For small companies, people can get their openid under their domain with as few as just a domain name if they use Google Apps.

This might be a good approach because people could use their Google Apps Account for the authentication, and they can still give out openids under their own domain which they could change the authentication backend for in the future. It is simple and extendable, but sadly it hasn't became the standard yet. So, if you use standard library like python-openid, you will encounter some problems.

To solve those problems, you have to patch python-openid yourself to follow Google's approach.

I ran into the same problem before and I have a patched version of python-openid v2.1.1 which works for me.

If you need, I could post my code after some cleanup. It was a quick patch, so don't expect too much :)

Comment: I would be grateful if you could post your code, no matter how messy it is if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I uploaded my patched version of python-openid-2.2.4 at http://github.com/adieu/python-openid/

Comment: You also might want to try http://github.com/hudora/django-googleappsauth - it is specifically constructed for the googleapps uscase

Answer (score 1):

I think you can give a try http://github.com/hudora/django-googleappsauth
but I found some bugs [trying to fix them and translating comments](https://github.com/simul14/django-googleappsauth)