# django login with google app acoounts

Tags: django, authentication

Well, I thought this shouldn't be a big problem. However, since I have spent more than one day on this, I think it is the time for asking help.

I have a simple django admin project and it works fine now. The problem is that I want to implement the feature that only allow the user login my admin site with particular google app domain, like @example.com. Then users doesn't have to manually create account and it is easy for me to manage users.

I believe this is a common feature required by many websites. So I do some search and I found some posts introduce some interesting libraries.

The post here are helpful:

[Google apps login in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313573/google-apps-login-in-django)

[What's the best solution for OpenID with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123369/whats-the-best-solution-for-openid-with-django?rq=1)

[Which openid / oauth library to connect a django project to Google Apps Accounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145453/which-openid-oauth-library-to-connect-a-django-project-to-google-apps-accounts)

The last one the one I think should work for me, but it doesn't.

I have installed the python-openid patch from adieu on github:https://github.com/adieu/python-openid 
and it still give the same error: 'OpenID authentication failed: HTTP Response status from identity URL host is not 200. Got status 404'

After some diggings, I cannot figure out the solution.

Then I start looking for 'Google Accounts Authentication and Authorization' see if I can build the whole thing by myself.

Now, my question, should I keep sticking on the exist django libraries or should I starts doing something from the beginnings.

So the ideal solution is either some hint for solving the error on python-openid or give the direction for next move (new libraries or Google Accounts Authentication and Authorization)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you look at django-social-auth? It has a google auth backend: http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/google.html

Comment: I will take a look. Appreciate for any help

Comment: Hey Jerry, I am currently looking to ways to do this as well. Did django-social-auth work out well?

Comment: @skeryl, I cannot recall everything, but I do remember I built this feature by myself from scratch. The link below is the one guide me for implementation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login?hl=de-DE; In fact implement such feature is not hard. Good luck

Comment: are you using the package registration redux to create the account. If so i have one solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, best thing you can use is [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth). Python social auth generates user with its own structure but you can define [pipeline](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/pipeline.html) and say that whenever python-social-auth creates new user, you can also create [django user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User).

Answer (score 0):

I made this https://github.com/burke-software/django-auth-gapps based off of a blog post at http://peterkropf.com/archives/13

It could certainly use some improvements. I found this post when searching to see if anyone had a better solution. But it does work according to your workflow.