# Which django OpenID library works with new Google OpenID

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, openid, google-openid

Since Google deprecated OpenID 2.0 https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID2

What django libraries are present which support the new settings?

I am trying to add Google OpenID using `django_openid_auth` (that's on launchpad) and getting a 400 error as response!!

What are the additional changes I should make so that `django_openid_auth` works with new Google config

Answer (score 1):

I would say [Python-social-auth](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/backends/google.html)  works well. I use it in almost every project and never gave any problem.